# .NET equivalent of Maven Parent Pom / Dependency Management

Tags: .net, msbuild

Is there an equivalent to these Maven features in .NET? For example, I have this:

```
A.sln
    Proj1.csproj
        <PackageReference="Something" Version="1.2.3"/>
    Proj2.csproj
        <PackageReference="Something" Version="1.2.3"/>
```

I want a consistent way to ensure that they use the **same** version for `Something`. I've tried using a `Version.props` and importing that in each `.csproj`, but it's just not as elegant or nice as Maven BOMs / `dependencyManagment` section in a parent pom.

Is there a more standard approach for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) is what you are looking for. It allows you to set solution-wide package versions (and anything else) in a way that flows down to all projects.

In your example, you'd have:

```
A.sln
Directory.Build.targets

    Proj1.csproj
        <PackageReference Include="Something" />
    Proj2.csproj
        <PackageReference Include="Something" />
```

Where `Directory.Build.targets` contains:

```xml
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Something" Version="1.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note the use of `Update="Something"` (rather than `Include`), and the **lack** of a specified version in the per-project PackageReferences.

This approach is very useful for setting package versions across many projects, but it can do more than that. I've also used it to include the same code analysis rules in every project, and to set the C# language version in one place for all projects. Anything in a per-project `.csproj` file can be moved to `Directory.Build.targets` if you want to standardize it across all projects.

Comment: Hat tip to Filip W's blog: [Solution-wide Nuget package version handling with MsBuild 15+](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/07/solution-wide-nuget-package-version-handling-with-msbuild-15/)